# Trouble using/installing pip3

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, pip

I would like to install pip for python 3. I check the following on my computer:

```
which python3
python3 --version
```

which return

```
/usr/bin/python3
Python 3.5.2
```

Since, I already installed python3. I dediced to install `pip3` along typing

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

But I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

which means that maybe pip3 is already installed? Then I tried

```
which pip3
```

I got nothing, and

```
pip3 --version
```

just to be sure but it returns

```
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

which proposed me the command I already tried.

What is happening here?

What do I need to do to get pip3 properly?

Comment: Is the `pip` command working, or `pip3.5` or similar?

Comment: Yes, `pip` is working.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to fix your installation:

```bsh
sudo apt purge python3-pip
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip
rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

([See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969463/python3-pip3-install-broken-on-ubuntu))

But I find it's very easy to break it again. There is a lot of talking about it:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5495
- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/969463/python3-pip3-install-broken-on-ubuntu

---

Instead of invoking `pip3` from its bin-script, you can always use:

```bsh
python3 -m pip --version
```

or every other command:

```bsh
python3 -m pip install package
```

Add an alias to your e.g. `.bashrc` to make `pip3` work as it should:

```bsh
alias pip3='python3 -m pip'
```